# Issue with fixed background images in Safari 5.1

Tags: css, safari, css-position

I've created a Tumblr theme with a somewhat complex background. It renders as coded in Chrome and Firefox but Safari is giving me trouble. Basically the two background images assigned to the `body` element seem to readjust whenever the viewport dimensions change and when scrolling. It looks really bad, and I've attached a perfect example of the problem below. [image: Issue in Safari]

Does anybody know what might be wrong here and how to fix it? I know the code is correct, so I think this is a Safari specific bug. The theme is located at http://blog.danielimmke.com/

**EDIT**: Apparently this issue happens *only* on the OSX version of Safari. The Windows version renders as coded.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We're experiencing the same thing at the moment: only on Safari 5.1 for Mac